# Safari Bookmarks not syncing via iCloud issue

Tags: mac, icloud, safari, bookmarks

I am frustrated by this issue that just appeared recently.

No matter what I do, any modification (rearranging, deletion) to the bookmarks are soon reverted.

the bookmarks are now totally out of sync with my iOS devices.

OS X version 10.11.3 (15D21)
Safari Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4)

Pls see my youtube vid for demo of the issue:
https://youtu.be/ktxo1VVEwBI

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset your Safari Bookmark. See this:

[How can I reset the Safari bookmarks in iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29090/how-can-i-reset-the-safari-bookmarks-in-icloud?rq=1)

Simplified steps:

1. Turn off iCloud Safari sync on all devices
2. Backup current bookmarks on Mac
3. Delete bookmarks on all devices
4. Turn on Safari syncing on Mac
5. Restore bookmark backup file to ~/Library/Safari folder
6. Turn on bookmark syncing on all iOS devices

The original author of these suggestions noted the following: "Once I turned syncing back on each device remained blank for quite some time. I’m not sure why but I was able to prod the system along by adding a fake bookmark on another device. This seemed to kick everything into gear and I was able to delete that fake bookmark on different device – which eventually deleted it across all devices."

Comment: Why do users have to constantly do this kind of work to fix chronic failures with Apple's cloud services?

Comment: Additional clarification for users of older devices: As of late 2019, Apple [guidance](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230) on iCloud syncing indicates that Safari bookmarks syncing is now only available for iOS devices running iOS 11 or later and macOS devices running macOS Sierra 10.12.