# How can I erase or reset iCloud bookmarks?

Tags: icloud, safari, bookmarks

I bought additional Mac. I set up everything basic and  also logged into iCloud.
And after that, Boom, my 1st(main) Mac “Favourite” bookmarks are messed up, mixed up.

- the line up is mixed up by new Mac basic Favourite bookmarks such as(Google, Yahoo, ), the ones I have deleted long ago - they’re useless.
- also 80% of my old bookmarks are moved out of the favourites just in a long line
- the bookmark tree(structure) has been completely taken back into details.
- some of the bookmark folders are emptied

Because there is no easy access towards bookmarks(etc. similar data) in iCloud, I have tried to manipulate with it counter of ways:

- so far this link has been the closest help towards my situation, but doesn’t work for me.
  ( [How can I reset the Safari bookmarks in iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29090/how-can-i-reset-the-safari-bookmarks-in-icloud?newreg=937f9ac3992d475590493a0a31ad211b) )

1. I have followed all the steps of this link the 2nd guide(because 1st is for the bookmarks duplication problem which I don’t have)

- I have unselected Safari backing up safari to iCloud from every device except the main Mac. And deleting all bookmarks in 2 separate ways.

2. deleting bookmarks from bookmarks menu > then importing them back from html
3. deleting bookmarks from bookmarks menu > then copying my hardcopy of bookmarks.plist file back to Safari Libarary.
4. just replacing bookmarks.plist with my hardcopy of bookmarks.plist file back to Safari Libarary.

Still not working (With options 2 - 3 my old setting of bookmarks remain from 3min. to about 12hours, but then in one point again it is overwritten by iCloud)

1. So is there a way how to erase/format iCloud/(or some of it’s cache)… ?
2. How can I reset my bookmark situation into "pre-using my 2nd mac era"?
3. If all this is solved. Is there a way that I can use same Favourite bookmark list in all my devices?

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 Macs logged into same iCloud at same time